# Integration testing :: OAuth 2.0 logins (Facebook)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, integration-testing, facebook-oauth

In order to write set of integration (end-2-end) tests I need to simulate user login with Facebook OAuth 2.0. With mocking of request/response flow everything works well, however I'm wondering if there's any (simple) way of authenticating the user in "real" world.

Right now I'm thinking about creation of test user on Facebook, then use Apache HTTPClient in order to authenticate user in facebook with login/password, then save cookie and emulate "click" on "allow" button when asked to do so. However is's a bit complicated and "hard" way, so I'm looking for some library available, or may be FaceBook provides some "test" tokens with fake data available?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

With help of [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty/Resty/Overview.html) it is possible to solve the task and create test users (**Scala**):

```
val authToken = resty.text("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=your_app_id" +
  "&client_secret=your_app_secret&grant_type=client_credentials")

val jsonResource: JSONResource = resty.json(
  "https://graph.facebook.com/your_app_id/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=Abra+Kadabra&" +
    "locale=en_US&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken.toString.split("=")(1)))

val token = URLEncoder.encode(jsonResource.get("access_token").asInstanceOf[String])

val userId = jsonResource.get("id").asInstanceOf[String]
```